# Programação modular em Java, chamada de métodos

Tags: java, array, loop

Precisava de ajuda para colocar o método menor e o maior a serem "ouvidos" no método principal. A lógica do programa é mostrar ao usuário qual o maior e o menor valor de um **vetor**.

**CÓDIGO:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class L6ex3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner e = new Scanner (System.in);
        int quantidade = 0;

        System.out.print("Quantos alunos serão cadastradas as idades?");
        quantidade = e.nextInt();

        int v[] = new int [quantidade];
        System.out.print ("Digite as idades");
        for (int i=0; i<quantidade; i++)
            v[i] =e.nextInt();



    }

    public int menorValor (int v[]){
        int menor =0;
        for (int i=0; i<v.length;i++)
            menor = v[i];

        for (int i=0; i<v.length; i++)
            if (v[i]<menor)
                menor =v[i];

        return menor;
    }

    public int maior (int v[]){
        int maior=0;
        for (int i=0; i<v.length;i++)
            if (v[i]> maior)
                maior = v[i];

        return maior;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para chamar os métodos `menorValor()` e `maiorValor()` você deve colocar o modificador `static` nos métodos.

```
public static int menorValor (int v[]){/*...*/}
public static int maiorValor (int v[]){/*...*/}
```

Depois, no seu método `main`,basta chamá-los normalmente:

```
   /* ... */
    System.out.println ("Maior valor: "+ maiorValor(v));
    System.out.println ("Menor valor: "+ menorValor(v));
```

Também sugiro você alterar o código do método `menorValor()` para o seguinte:

```
public static int menorValor (int v[]){

    int menor =0;

    for (int i=0; i<v.length;i++)
        if(v[i] < menor)
            menor = v[i]

    return menor;
}
```

Comment: Cara, valeu demais a ajuda. Deu certinho. Quanto a sua sugestão, eu havia feito dessa maneira, mas se o usuário entrar com qualquer número maior que 0 ele vai retornar 0, pois o menor já começa valendo 0. Abraços.

Comment: Nesse caso, você pode iniciar a variável `menor` com um número muito alto, por exemplo **10000**, pois o ideal é que você não tenha muitos loops de **for** desnecessários. E lembrando, a melhor maneira de agradeçar uma boa resposta é aceitando-a como "melhor resposta"  :)

Comment: Pensei nessas hipóteses também, realmente de mais vale dar uma miguelada e colocar negativo do que aumentar um for.. rsrs.. até mesmo "computacionalmente" falando.. Vlw cara, vou nessa. Aprovei a resposta...

Answer (score 1):

Nunca atribua um valor qualquer, mesmo que seja um ZERO. Você nao sabe se o valor é maior ou menor que o digitado.

- Sugiro que sempre pegue o primeiro valor do array como default, assim
  ele faz parte dessa comparação.
- Ou, utilize o valor máximo ou mínimo    suportado pelo tipo do array.
  (Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)

Se vc for chamar dentro da função principal 'main', vc deve deixar os dois metodos static. Caso não queira deixar static, coloque dentro de uma Classe (na minha opnião seria o ideal).